# exit gulp when build is finished

Tags: gulp, gulp-uglify

I'm using gulp to minify CSS and JS files.

When I run the gulp command `gulp build:website1:desktop` from a terminal, it finishes successfully but it does not return to the shell prompt, I have to run `Ctrl+C` to return to the command prompt

Here is a what I'm using

```
gulp.task('build:website1:desktop', function () {
runSequence(
    'website1:desktop:scripts',
    'website1:desktop:css');
  })
```

Any ideas How to exit and return to the command prompt without typing `Ctrl+C` every time?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do your subtasks website1:desktop:scripts and website1:desktop:css have return statements?

Comment: indeed, those subtasks have return statements.

Answer (score 1):

First thing is to make sure that your `scripts` and `css` tasks return a stream or a promise, so that `runSequence` knows when these tasks are finished. For most gulp tasks, using the return statement with `gulp.src(…)` will do just that:

```
gulp.task('website1:desktop:scripts', function() {
  return gulp.src(…)
    .pipe(doSomething())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(…));
});
```

Next thing is to provide a callback for `runSequence`:

```
gulp.task('build:website1:desktop', function (callback) {
  runSequence(
    'website1:desktop:scripts',
    'website1:desktop:css',
    callback);
});
```

This should do the trick.