# NodeJS Spawn does not exit when calling docker exec

Tags: node.js, docker, process, tty

I'm trying to run `docker exec` commands using NodeJS `childProcess.spawn` but the process never "exits". I've tried libraries such as `pty.js` but these never emit "exit" either.

I added `-t` to the command and while this does change the output to have full color support, it still doesn't trigger an "exit" event.

My full command:
`docker exec -it frontend-container gulp build`

This is the code I am running. `this.terminal.spawn` just calls `spawn` on the `pty.js` library.

```
const cProcess = this.terminal.spawn(cmd, matches);

cProcess.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log('data', data);
});

cProcess.on('exit', (data) => {
  console.log('Exit');
});
```

The `data` event is called perfectly but `exit` is never called. This is using the `pty.js` framework.

Answer (score 0):

Docker exec exit when the processes exist that start in the command.
For example

```
docker exec -it admin ash -c "ls /"
```

[image]

If your processes is some thing like tailing log so it will only exit `ctrl+c`

For exmaple

```
docker exec -it admin ash -c "pm2 logs"
```

In our CI testing, we just call

```
docker exec -t nodejs ash -c "cd /opt/nodejs/ ; npm test"
```

Now the exec will exit when exit trigger from npm test command.
And this is how we handle at nodejs

```
 var gulp = require('gulp');
var mocha = require("gulp-mocha");

gulp.task("buildTests", function () {
  return gulp.src([
    "./test/build/test*.js"
  ]).pipe(mocha({exit: true}));
});
```

Check these link

https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/411

[exit gulp when build is finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43794077/exit-gulp-when-build-is-finished)

https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/903

http://derrickbowen.com/blog/content/stop-gulp-build-unit-test-failure
https://www.npmjs.com/package/docker-exec

https://www.npmjs.com/package/docker-cli-js